# Convert string to dd/mm/yyyy format in j query

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a three dropdowns `for showing date`. 
The values for day and month are showing as 1, 2, 3,.... for both. Now i need final date as `01/01/2012`.

How can i do this in `Jquery`. I am facing problem in appending a `0 for values less than 10`. I am looking for a concise and optimum solution.

Comment: @MichalKlouda My apologies. I will remove as nonconstructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have done complete solution bin, you can check demo link too..

For Above solution, You have include file latest jQuery.js and date.format.js

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp6w

**HTML**

```
<select id="seldd">
  <option value="1">
    1
  </option>
  <option value="2">
    2
  </option>
  <option value="3">
    3
  </option>
  <option value="4">
    4
  </option>
  <option value="5">
    5
  </option>
  <option value="6">
    6
  </option>
  <option value="7">
    7
  </option>
  <option value="8">
    8
  </option>
  <option value="9">
    9
  </option>
  <option value="10">
    10
  </option>
</select>
<select id="selmm">
  <option value="1">
    1
  </option>
  <option value="2">
    2
  </option>
  <option value="3">
    3
  </option>
  <option value="4">
    4
  </option>
  <option value="5">
    5
  </option>
  <option value="6">
    6
  </option>
  <option value="7">
    7
  </option>
  <option value="8">
    8
  </option>
  <option value="9">
    9
  </option>
  <option value="10">
    10
  </option>
  <option value="11">
    11
  </option>
  <option value="12">
    12
  </option>
</select>
<select id="selyy">
  <option value="2012">
    2012
  </option>
  <option value="2011">
    2011
  </option>
  <option value="2010">
    2010
  </option>
  <option value="2009">
    2009
  </option>
  <option value="2008">
    2008
  </option>
  <option value="2007">
    2007
  </option>
  <option value="2006">
    2006
  </option>
  <option value="2005">
    2005
  </option>
  <option value="2004">
    2004
  </option>
  <option value="2003">
    2003
  </option>
  <option value="2002">
    2002
  </option>
  <option value="2001">
    2001
  </option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Convert into Date" id="btn1" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        var strdt = $("#seldd").val().trim() + "/" + $("#selmm").val().trim() + "/" + $("#selyy").val().trim();

        var thisDate = new Date(Date.parse(strdt));
        alert(dateFormat(thisDate, "dd/mm/yyyy"));
    });

});
```

**Demo** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp6w

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing in jQuery for handling dates, you would use plain Javascript:

```
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var day = date.GetDate();

var formatted = (day<10?'0':'') + day + '/' + (month<10?'0':'') + month + '/' + year;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this, jQuery [dateFormat plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat). That might be what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you can benefit from [data.js](http://www.datejs.com/)